# Cascading Combobox with default values on telerik mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I have a search page and want to add some filters to it, my setup is quite simple, I have a CombobBox for Countries and a ComboBox for States.

I want to show ALL the states if no country is selected(actually, the first item of the countries combobox is "All") here is my code:

```
    @(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(m => m.Country)
         .Name("cbxCountry")
         .BindTo(this.Model.CountryList)
         .SelectedIndex(0).CascadeTo("cbxStates"))

    @(Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(m=>m.State)
         .Name("cbxStates")
         .DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax()
         .Select("AjaxLoadStates","States")))
```

Note that even if the .SelectedIndex is set to 1, 3, 1231231 the second combobox keeps disabled until I select a value. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [client API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html) in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectFirstCountry() {
        var cbxCountry = $("#cbxCountry").data('tComboBox')
        var cbxStates = $("#cbxStates").data('tComboBox')

        cbxCountry.select(1);
        cbxStates.enable();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        @{
            Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady("SelectFirstCountry()");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice approach,
I abbandoned the cascadeTo here(before that, I actually changed telerik's code just to see if I could make thinks better).
But your solution looks very clean, thanks :D